# My F# code is much longer than the equivalent python one, anything wrong?

Tags: f#

I'm converting an existing `python` code to `F#` the number of lines increased so much, not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or there is a wy to optimize it:

I've this `Array` which I want to process:

```
let series = [|30;21;29;31;40;48;53;47;37;39;31;29;17;9;20;24;27;35;41;38;
          27;31;27;26;21;13;21;18;33;35;40;36;22;24;21;20;17;14;17;19;
          26;29;40;31;20;24;18;26;17;9;17;21;28;32;46;33;23;28;22;27;
          18;8;17;21;31;34;44;38;31;30;26;32|]
```

in `Python` it is:

```
series = [30,21,29,31,...,26,32]
```

**PART 1**

In `Python` I've this:

```
def initial_seasonal_components(series, slen):
    seasonals = {}
    season_averages = []
    n_seasons = int(len(series)/slen)
    # compute season averages
    for j in range(n_seasons):
        season_averages.append(sum(series[slen*j:slen*j+slen])/float(slen))
```

While converting into `F#` I ended up with this:

```
open System.Collections.Generic 
let initial_seasonal_components (series : int []) (slen : int) : Dictionary<int, double>  =
    let seasonals = new Dictionary<int, double>()
    let mutable seasonAverages = []
    let nSeasons = series.Length / slen 
    // compute season averages
    for i in 0 .. nSeasons-1 do
        seasonAverages  <- 
            series
                |> Array.sub <|| (slen * i, slen)
                |> Array.sum
                |> float
                |> fun s -> s / (slen |> float)
                |> fun e -> [e]
                |> List.append seasonAverages
```

**PART 2**

In `Python` I've this:

```
for i in range(slen):
    sum_of_vals_over_avg = 0.0
    for j in range(n_seasons):
        sum_of_vals_over_avg += series[slen*j+i]-season_averages[j]
    seasonals[i] = sum_of_vals_over_avg/n_seasons
```

While converting into `F#` I ended up with this:

```
for i in 0 .. slen-1 do
    let mutable sumOfValsOverAvg = 0.0
    for j in 0 .. nSeasons-1 do
        sumOfValsOverAvg <- 
            series 
                |> Array.item (slen*j+i)
                |> float
                |> fun el -> el + sumOfValsOverAvg - seasonAverages.[j]

    seasonals.Add (i, sumOfValsOverAvg / (nSeasons |> float))
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or this is really the optimized code I can get!!

**UPDATE**

Below the full 'Python` code from [here](https://grisha.org/blog/2016/02/17/triple-exponential-smoothing-forecasting-part-iii/):

```
series = [30,21,29,31,40,48,53,47,37,39,31,29,17,9,20,24,27,35,41,38,
          27,31,27,26,21,13,21,18,33,35,40,36,22,24,21,20,17,14,17,19,
          26,29,40,31,20,24,18,26,17,9,17,21,28,32,46,33,23,28,22,27,
          18,8,17,21,31,34,44,38,31,30,26,32]

def initial_seasonal_components(series, slen):
    seasonals = {}
    season_averages = []
    n_seasons = int(len(series)/slen)
    # compute season averages
    for j in range(n_seasons):
        season_averages.append(sum(series[slen*j:slen*j+slen])/float(slen))
    sarr = [str(a) for a in season_averages]
    print(", " . join(sarr))
    # compute initial values
    for i in range(slen):
        sum_of_vals_over_avg = 0.0
        for j in range(n_seasons):
            sum_of_vals_over_avg += series[slen*j+i]-season_averages[j]
        seasonals[i] = sum_of_vals_over_avg/n_seasons

    return seasonals
```

and here my equivalent `F#` code:

```
open System.Collections.Generic  // for Dictionary

let series = [|30;21;29;31;40;48;53;47;37;39;31;29;17;9;20;24;27;35;41;38;
          27;31;27;26;21;13;21;18;33;35;40;36;22;24;21;20;17;14;17;19;
          26;29;40;31;20;24;18;26;17;9;17;21;28;32;46;33;23;28;22;27;
          18;8;17;21;31;34;44;38;31;30;26;32|]

let initialAeasonalComponents (series : int []) slen : Dictionary<int, double>  =
    let seasonals = new Dictionary<int, double>()
    let mutable seasonAverages = []
    let nSeasons = series.Length / slen 
    // compute season averages
    for i in 0 .. nSeasons-1 do
        seasonAverages  <- 
            series
                |> Array.sub <|| (slen * i, slen)
                |> Array.sum
                |> float
                |> fun s -> s / (slen |> float)
                |> fun e -> [e]
                |> List.append seasonAverages 

    printfn "Seasons Averageß: \n %A" seasonAverages
    // compute initial values
    for i in 0 .. slen-1 do
        let mutable sumOfValsOverAvg = 0.0
        for j in 0 .. nSeasons-1 do
            sumOfValsOverAvg <- 
                series 
                    |> Array.item (slen*j+i)
                    |> float
                    |> fun el -> el + sumOfValsOverAvg - seasonAverages.[j]

        seasonals.Add (i, sumOfValsOverAvg / (nSeasons |> float))
    printfn "Seasons Averageß: \n %A" seasonals
    seasonals

initialAeasonalComponents series 12
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to think in a different way, in F# mutability is not the default.

For part 1 you can do this:

```
open System.Collections.Generic 
let initial_seasonal_components (series : int []) (slen : int) =
    let seasonals = new Dictionary<int, double>()
    series |> Array.map float |> Array.chunkBySize slen |> Array.map Array.average
```

For part 2 you can also take a different approach:

```
[|0..slen-1|] 
    |> Array.map (fun i -> 
            i, Array.zip grouped seasonAverages
            |> Array.fold (fun s (els, av) -> els.[i] + s - av) 0.)
    |> Array.map (fun (i, x) -> i, x / float nSeasons)
    |> dict
```

Combining all parts you can write it like this:

```
let initialAeasonalComponents (series : int []) slen : IDictionary<int, double>  =
    let nSeasons = float  (series.Length / slen)
    let grouped = series |> Array.map float |> Array.chunkBySize slen
    let seasonAverages = grouped |> Array.map Array.average
    Array.init slen (fun i -> i, (Array.zip grouped seasonAverages 
                                    |> Array.fold (fun s (els, av) -> els.[i] + s - av) 0.)
                                        / nSeasons) |> dict
```

Notice that the key differences with the Python approach is that we use more higher order functions and we don't use mutability, which makes easier to reason about your code.

Also notice that now the F# code is even a bit shorter than the Python one ;)

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with the full code, note: I'm coming from `C#` new for both `Python` and `F#`

Comment: What represents each component in the dictionary?

Comment: It is a nap representing season number and season average

Comment: WONDERFUL, thanks a lot, what is the meaning of `0.` at the end of the code `(Array.zip ... 0.)`

Comment: That's the seed value for the ``Array.fold`` which will initially feed the parameter ``s``.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163117/discussion-between-hasan-a-yousef-and-gustavo).

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you help in this as well :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/48243846/2441637