# The result of this expression is implicitly ignored. Consider using 'ignore' e.g. 'expr |> ignore', or ' e.g. 'let result = expr'

Tags: f#

I'm trying to build `F#` equivalent code for the `Python` code appearing [here](https://grisha.org/blog/2016/02/17/triple-exponential-smoothing-forecasting-part-iii/), I've the below code:

```
let tripleExponentialSmoothing series slen alpha beta gamma nPreds =
    let result : float list = []
    let mutable smooth = 0.
    let mutable trend = 0.
    let seasonals = initialSeasonalComponents series 12
    for i in 0..(series.Length+nPreds-1) do
    match i with
    | 0 ->     // initial values        
        smooth <- series |> Array.head |> float
        trend <- initialTrend series slen
        result |> List.append [series |> Array.head |> float] |> ignore
    | i when i >= series.Length -> // we are forecasting
        let m = i - series.Length + 1
        result |> List.append [(smooth + float m * trend) + seasonals.Item(i%slen)] |> ignore
    | _ -> 
        let v = series |> Array.head  |> float
        let lastSmooth = smooth
        smooth <- alpha*(v-seasonals.Item(i%slen)) + (1.-alpha)*(smooth+trend)
        trend <- beta * (smooth-lastSmooth) + (1.-beta)*trend
        seasonals.Item(i%slen) <- gamma*(v-smooth) + (1.-gamma)*seasonals.Item(i%slen)
        result |> List.append [smooth + trend + seasonals.Item(i%slen)] |> ignore
    result
```

For which I got the below error:

> warning FS0020: The result of this expression is implicitly ignored.
>   Consider using 'ignore' to discard this value explicitly, e.g. 'expr
>   |> ignore', or 'let' to bind the result to a name, e.g. 'let result =
>   expr'.

I tried to write the above as conversion of the below `Python` code:

```
def triple_exponential_smoothing(series, slen, alpha, beta, gamma, n_preds):
    result = []
    seasonals = initial_seasonal_components(series, slen)
    for i in range(len(series)+n_preds):
        if i == 0: # initial values
            smooth = series[0]
            trend = initial_trend(series, slen)
            result.append(series[0])
            continue
        if i >= len(series): # we are forecasting
            m = i - len(series) + 1
            result.append((smooth + m*trend) + seasonals[i%slen])
        else:
            val = series[i]
            last_smooth, smooth = smooth, alpha*(val-seasonals[i%slen]) + (1-alpha)*(smooth+trend)
            trend = beta * (smooth-last_smooth) + (1-beta)*trend
            seasonals[i%slen] = gamma*(val-smooth) + (1-gamma)*seasonals[i%slen]
            result.append(smooth+trend+seasonals[i%slen])
    return result
```

What the wrong things I did, and what is the correct code equivalent to the mentioned `Python`'s one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running the for as a side effect.

Maybe you want to a seq expression, I think in Python you have generators but here in F# remember that everything is an expression.

```
let tripleExponentialSmoothing series slen alpha beta gamma nPreds =
    let mutable smooth = 0.
    let mutable trend = 0.
    let seasonals = initialSeasonalComponents series 12 |> Dictionary 
    seq {
        for i in 0..(series.Length+nPreds-1) do
          match i with
          | 0 ->     // initial values        
              smooth <- series |> Array.head |> float
              trend <- initialTrend series slen
              yield series |> Array.head |> float
          | i when i >= series.Length -> // we are forecasting
              let m = i - series.Length + 1
              yield (smooth + float m * trend) + seasonals.[i%slen]
          | _ -> 
              let v = series |> Array.head  |> float
              let lastSmooth = smooth
              smooth <- alpha*(v-seasonals.[i%slen]) + (1.-alpha)*(smooth+trend)
              trend <- beta * (smooth-lastSmooth) + (1.-beta)*trend
              seasonals.[i%slen] <- gamma*(v-smooth) + (1.-gamma)*seasonals.[i%slen]
              yield smooth + trend + seasonals.[i%slen] }
```

So, a sequence expressions is of the form `seq {  expr  }` and inside the expression you use `yield` to yield results.

Comment: I think the OP was thinking that `result |> List.append [x]` would append `<x>` to the list, so I imagine the sequence expression version would just have `yield <x>` and no `result` variable.

Comment: I see, @hasan if you can provide an example of inputs and outputs, it might help.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to cal the function using `let f = tripleExponentialSmoothing series 12 0.716 0.029 0.993 24
printfn "Forecast: \n %A" f` but got this error `Forecast:
 Error: Exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' was thrown.`

Comment: About my algorithm, I'm trying to replicate this one: https://grisha.org/blog/2016/02/17/triple-exponential-smoothing-forecasting-part-iii/

Comment: @HasanAYousef I think the problem was that the dictionary you are getting from the function in your previous question is not mutable, so I added a conversion here. It should work now.

Comment: Also note that you can use ``.[x]`` instead of ``.Item(x)``. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answer, you are trying to mutate the list of results in the `for` loop, but this is not possible, because F# lists are immutable by default.

If you want to directly follow the style of the Python code, you can use mutable `ResizeArray`:

```
let tripleExponentialSmoothing series slen alpha beta gamma nPreds =
    let result = ResizeArray<_>()
    let mutable smooth = 0.
    let mutable trend = 0.
    let seasonals = initialSeasonalComponents series 12
    for i in 0..(series.Length+nPreds-1) do
      match i with
      | 0 ->     // initial values        
          smooth <- series |> Array.head |> float
          trend <- initialTrend series slen
          result.Add(series |> Array.head |> float)
      | i when i >= series.Length -> // we are forecasting
          let m = i - series.Length + 1
          result.Add((smooth + float m * trend) + seasonals.Item(i%slen))
      | _ -> 
          let v = series |> Array.head  |> float
          let lastSmooth = smooth
          smooth <- alpha*(v-seasonals.Item(i%slen)) + (1.-alpha)*(smooth+trend)
          trend <- beta * (smooth-lastSmooth) + (1.-beta)*trend
          seasonals.Item(i%slen) <- gamma*(v-smooth) + (1.-gamma)*seasonals.Item(i%slen)
          result.Add(smooth + trend + seasonals.Item(i%slen))
```

This is not very idiomatic F# code, but it solves your immediate problem. For a more functional solution, you can go with sequence expressions as mentioned by Gustavo and yield results one by one, but you still keep `smooth` and `trend` as mutable variables, so there probably is even nicer way of doing this - but that's hard to guess without knowing more about your algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, I got this error: `System.NotSupportedException: Exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' was thrown.
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.ExtraTopLevelOperators+dictValueType@98[TKey,T].System-Collections-Generic-IDictionary`2-set_Item (TKey key, T value) [0x00015] in <59f0bcfedff9fae1a7450383febcf059>:0
  at FSI_0001.tripleExponentialSmoothing (System.Int32[] series, System.Int32 slen, System.Double alpha, System.Double beta, System.Double gamma, System.Int32 nPreds) [0x00173] in <a0e388895c50450ab5d4aef3108fb8e7>:0`

Comment: About my algorithm, I'm trying to replicate this one: https://grisha.org/blog/2016/02/17/triple-exponential-smoothing-forecasting-part-iii/

Comment: The error is probably that you use `dict [ .. ]` which creates an immutable dictionary in `initialSeasonalComponents` and so the call `seasonals.Item(..) <- ..` fails. You can return mutable `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_, _>()` instead, but you omitted that part of code...